# How can I access the observable in my custom binding?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) to edit the date and time of one of the properties of my observable. It works fine when I am creating a new record but not to edit one that is already created.

My custom binding is as follows

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datetimepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var options = {
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A',
            locale: 'en-AU',
            sideBySide: true,
            defaultDate: ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())
        };

        ko.utils.extend(options, allBindings.dateTimePickerOptions);

        $(element).datetimepicker(options).on("dp.change", function (evntObj) {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            if (evntObj.timeStamp !== undefined) {
                var picker = $(this).data("DateTimePicker");
                var d = picker.date();
                if (ko.isObservable(observable)) {
                    observable(d.format(options.format));
                } else {
                    valueAccessor(d.format(options.format));
                    console.log("Not observable");
                }
                console.log(observable, "\n", $(element).val());
            }
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        $(element).datetimepicker('date', value || '');
    }
};
```

And here is the relevant part of my ViewModel

```
var PicksViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.pick = ko.observable();
    self.newPick = {
        Title: ko.observable(),
        Sport: ko.observable(),
        MatchTime: ko.observable(),
        PublishTime: ko.observable(),
        HomeTeam: ko.observable(),
        AwayTeam: ko.observable(),
        Analysis: ko.observable(),
        PickSummary: ko.observable()
    };
}
```

`newPick` and `pick` are used for 2 separate forms. One to create a new one and one to edit an existing pick. When I use the datepicker for a new pick it works as intended and I don't get a console log that says `Not observable` but when I edit an existing pick the observable isn't passed to the binding and therefore doesn't get updated and I get the console log.

#### How can I get the observable passed to my custom binding?

I am using the following html for my binding

```
<form data-bind="with:pick">
    <!-- Rest of form omitted -->
    <div class="input-group date" id="editMatchTimePicker">
        <input type="text" data-bind="datetimepicker:MatchTime">
    </div>
</form>
```

**Update**
I fixed it by binding to a separate observable and using a computed observable to handle the conversion between UTC and local times.

```
self.editMatchTime = ko.observable();
self.localMatchTime = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function () {
        self.editMatchTime(self.pick().MatchTime);
        var local = moment.utc(self.pick().MatchTime).local().format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss");
        return local;
    },
    write: function(value) {
        var utcTime = moment(value).utc();
        self.editMatchTime(utcTime);
    },
    owner: self
});
```

And then my binding changed to

```
<input type="text" data-bind="datetimepicker:$root.localMatchTime">
```

Comment: I've tried to reconstruct your scenario, but there are some missing pieces. In the code you've posted `pick` is empty, and it's kind of hard to imagine what goes into it (especially since there is no `Pick` constructor function, and the `newPick` is just a plain object...). Please try to convert your code example into a runnable snippet.

Comment: Also, you're executing all sorts of logic in your view when binding with your custom binding. It would make more sense if you bound to either `MatchTime` directly, or a writeable `computed` with all that logic inside it. Currently I'd assume your problem lies in that bit.

Comment: I've edited my post with what I've tried (just binding to datetimepicker:MatchTime) and that didn't fix it. I have added [a gist](https://gist.github.com/mhcodner/375b5da7a2ca66935b9e) to show how I set the pick with example data returned from the API. `self.getPick` is triggered when I click on the edit button from the list of all picks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not binding an observable to your `datetimepicker`, you're binding a value which is converted from the observable `MatchTime`. You could bind `MatchTime` itself and do the conversion inside the handler, or you can use the `allBindings` parameter to get at the `value`-bound observable. If you bind the observable itself, you can roll the `value`-binding functionality into your custom binding handlers so that you only have to make one binding. (See the "Simple Wrapper Binding" section [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html).)

Comment: Where you do `console.log("Not observable");`, have it include `observable` so you can see what it's getting: `console.log("Not observable", observable);`
It sounds like, since it's only a problem with an existing pick, that at some point you're assigning a new value to MatchTime instead of setting its contents.

Comment: With the console log a few lines down `console.log(observable, "\n", $(element).val());`, that gives me: `2016-01-05T22:00:00 
 06/01/2016 12:00 AM` when I incremented it by 2 hours. As you can see the input is updated but `observable` just returns the original value of MatchTime not the observable.

Comment: Have it include the observable so you can see what it's getting. At some point your observable is becoming not an observable.

Comment: I ended up fixing this by creating another observable for the matchtime and I use a writable computed observable to handle converting between local and UTC. I marked you as answer because you stated that I wasn't binding to an observable which got me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use, seems that you're missing this initialization `picker.date(value);`

```js
  ko.bindingHandlers.datetimePicker = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            var options = {
                showTodayButton: true,
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
                sideBySide: true,
                locale: 'es'
            };

            ko.utils.extend(options, allBindingsAccessor().dateTimePickerOptions);
            var $el = $(element).datetimepicker(options);
            var picker = $el.data("DateTimePicker");

            picker.date(value);

            $el.on("dp.change", function (ev) {
                var observable = valueAccessor();
                if ($el.is(':focus')) {
                    // Don't update while the user is in the field...
                    // Instead, handle focus loss
                    $el.one('blur', function (ev) {
                        var dateVal = picker.date();
                        observable(dateVal);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    observable(ev.date);
                }
            });
            //handle removing an element from the dom
            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                picker.destroy();
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            $(element).data("DateTimePicker").date(value);
        }
    };
```